# Unit testing mock DbContext DbSet<> is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

Trying to write unit tests that run against `DbContext`, in .Net Core. I have performed the same in full framework EF and all works.

The code below represents the minimum code to recreate the issue. I have stripped out anything that isn't implemented

I have the following mocks

```
// DbContext
public class MockDbContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<State> State { get; set; }
}
```

The Repository

```
// Mock of my repository
public class MockRepository<TModel> : IRepository<TModel> where TModel : class
{
    MockDbContext _context;
    DbSet<TModel> _dbSet;

    public MockRepository(MockDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        // THIS IS NULL
        _dbSet = _context.Set<TModel>();
    }

    public async Task<IList<TModel>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return _dbSet.ToListAsync().Result;
    }

    public void Add(TModel t)
    {
        _context.Add(t);
    }
}
```

The Unit of work

```
// Unit of work
public class MockUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private Mock<MockDbContext> _mockDbContext;
    private IRepository<State> _stateRepo;

    public MockUnitOfWork()
    {
        var mockState = new List<State>() { new State { StateId = 1, Name = "Added" }, new State { StateId = 1, Name = "Deleted" } }.AsQueryable();

        var mockStateSet = new Mock<DbSet<State>>();
        mockStateSet.As<IQueryable<State>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(mockState.Provider);
        mockStateSet.As<IQueryable<State>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(mockState.Expression);
        mockStateSet.As<IQueryable<State>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(mockState.ElementType);
        mockStateSet.As<IQueryable<State>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(mockState.GetEnumerator());


        _mockDbContext = new Mock<MockDbContext>();
        _mockDbContext.Setup(o => o.State).Returns(mockStateSet.Object);
    }       
    public void SaveAsync()
    {
        _mockDbContext.Object.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IRepository<State> StateRepository => _stateRepo ?? (_stateRepo = new MockRepository<State>(_mockDbContext.Object));
}
```

I'm attempting to test some service code, which isn't included here, though the problem can be recreated by calling the following, from a test method.

```
MockUnitOfWork unitOfWork = new MockUnitOfWork();
var x = unitOfWork.StateRepository.GetAllAsync().Result;
```

We also have an extension that implements pretty much what can be found [Entity Framework Testing with a Mocking Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx) under the testing async section. This also results in a null on the `DbSet<>`

Any idea what i might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Entity Framework Core, the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory` NuGet package provides the infrastructure required for testing scenarios. Your repository can then use an appropriate `DbContext`, and your unit of work can accept an appropriate repository.

Additional details about testing with the InMemory provider in EF Core can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory.

Comment: Thank you. It's perfect and allows me to do away with much of the mocking.